# Table with dynamic number of rows and columns, sorted vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have an question. I have an table, that is dynamically populated with titles from an API. Lets say it looks like the picture below.

[image: How it looks]

What I want to do, is that instead of it being sorted alphabetically, horizontally, I want it do be sorted alphabetically vertically. something like the picture below:

[image: How I want]

In addition, the number of columns and rows should be dynamic, inside of the parent container, because I can not know the returned number of elements. Also the size of each box must be dynamic, as I do not know the size of each element.

I have added the HTML structure as below. PS needs to support IE 11.

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="ulList"> 
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Aliquet justo orci </div>            
    </li>
    <li class="element">            
        <div class="subelement">Donec efficitur nibh</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Duis aliquam leo</div>            
    </li>
    <li class="element" >
        <div class="subelement">Duis aliquam leo id malesuada ultricies</div>            
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Lorem </div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Lorem  - ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Mauris a dolor lacinia, sollicitudin justo</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Morbi dignissim ultricies orci</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Nullam at turpis at sem condimentum sodales ac</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Nulla facilisi</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Vestibulum scelerisque, est sed vestibulum interdum,</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">  
        <div class="subelement">Vivamus</div>
    </li>        
    <li class="element">  
        <div class="subelement">Vivamus-tristique</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Vivamus-ultrices</div>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ulList"> 
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Aenean</div>        
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Aenean id magna vitae</div>     
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Cras cursus est a urna </div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Donec efficitur nibh sollicitudin</div>     
    </li>
    <li class="element" >
        <div class="subelement">Duis aliquam leo id</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Duis volutpat lacus at fermentum</div>      
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Etiam ultricies nisl sit amet justo</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Fusce ex turpis</div>
    </li>       
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Morbi sit amet</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Nullam at turpis</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">            
        <div class="subelement">Vestibulum</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Sollicitudin </div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Vivamus</div>
    </li>   
    <li class="element">
        <div class="subelement">Vivamus ultrices enim eu turpis</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: forgot to mention, I would also like that each element is the same height on each row. So, basically, the highest element should decide the hight of the rest of the elements.

Edit 2: Added css.

Have tried css grid, but I know that IE11 does not like it to much. In addition, I need to specify number of rows...

```
.ulList {
border: solid 1px pink;
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
grid-gap: 2vw;
grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

I have also tried with flex, but could not get it to work without setting a height... And have trouble with the items exiting the parent box

```
.ulList {
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
height: 200px;
}
```

[image: Uneaven row heights]

As the image above shows, using @Jenifer Jiang solution with "columns = 4",  when an text breaks into two lines, the height of each item differs, I need that each row has the same height as the heighest element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the attribute column-count to set the column count you want. Then it will display automatically. And pay attention that you should add margin to li so that the list bullet will show normally.

Here is my CSS code.

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .ulList {
        column-count: 4;
        column-gap: 2px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .element {
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
 </style>
```

[image: running result]

Comment: I did try that, however, when a text breaks into two lines, the item height will be different on each row. I will update my original post, to show you that the row height differs. I need each row to be the same height, as the highest element.